# Groupby itertools gives different groups with the same key

Tags: python, split, group-by, python-itertools

I am grouping string elements within a list by the first word and by the last word in the string. I am using `groupby` from `itertools` to do the grouping. The process seems to work fine for the last word, however it doesn't seem to do the same for the first one.

```
from itertools import groupby

model_eval_cols = ['MAD model meFuelFlowStar', 'MedAD model meFuelFlowStar', 'MAD model rpmStar', 'MedAD model rpmStar']

for k, v in groupby(model_eval_cols, key=lambda x: x.split(' ')[2]):
    print(k, list(v))
```

The above outputs

```
meFuelFlowStar ['MAD model meFuelFlowStar', 'MedAD model meFuelFlowStar']
rpmStar ['MAD model rpmStar', 'MedAD model rpmStar']
```

However if I try to get the strings grouped by the first word:

```
for k, v in groupby(model_eval_cols, key=lambda x: x.split(' ')[0]):
    print(k, list(v))
```

It doesn't seem to work

```
MAD ['MAD model meFuelFlowStar']
MedAD ['MedAD model meFuelFlowStar']
MAD ['MAD model rpmStar']
MedAD ['MedAD model rpmStar']
```

This surprises me as the keys are the same

Comment: The documentation of [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) says: "Generally, the iterable needs to already be sorted on the same key function."

Answer (score 5):

`groupby` assumes that the elements in the same group appear consecutively (i.e. basically the list is sorted). Right at the beginning of [`groupby`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) it says:

> Make an iterator that returns **consecutive keys and groups from the
>   iterable.** The key is a function computing a key value for each
>   element. If not specified or is None, key defaults to an identity
>   function and returns the element unchanged. **Generally, the iterable
>   needs to already be sorted on the same key function.**

Your list is not sorted. So sort it before `groupby`. Define a key function to be used by `sorted` and `groupby`:

```
def first_word(sentence):
    return sentence.split()[0]
```

And then:

```
groupby(sorted(meFuelFlowStar, key=first_word), key=first_word)
```